# Vim: How to generate sql "IN" clause

Tags: vim

This may be simple request inside Vim: would like to take a list (current buffer) and wrap each line in single quotes, each separated by a comma and then surrounded by parenthesis (perhaps also removing leading/trailing space or empty lines if present).

Start with:

```
999886
999887
999888
999893
999894
999895
999896
999897
```

Result:

```
('999886',
'999887',
'999888',
'999893',
'999894',
'999895',
'999896',
'999897')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are many ways you can do to achieve it. Assume that your cursor is on line 1, col1, you can do:

```
<c-v>GI'<Esc>gvA',<esc>i(<esc>}r)
```

You just press those keystrokes one by one, you will see how the text was 
changed.

Or with command:

```
:%s/.*/'&',<CR>
```

then:

```
}r){i(<esc>
```

The 2nd approach is useful when the lines have different length.

You can also record macro to do it.